# Tirar números juntos a letra com o str_replace

Tags: php, string

estou querendo tirar uma parte de uma string, mais especificamente números junto a letra, como por exemplo:

```
$string = "Parte da string - 60h"
```

Pois bem, uso o str_replace da seguinte forma:

```
$string = str_replace(' - ', '', $string);
$string = str_replace('[ˆ0-99]h', '', $string);
```

O problema é que obtenho a seguinte string : Parte da string60h. Me parece que o segundo uso do str_replace não está sendo feito. Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O **str_replace** não aceita expressão regular, você pode usar o **preg_replace ()**.

```
$string = preg_replace('/[0-9]+h/', '', $string);
```

Comment: PERFEITO! Exatamente o que eu queria.